# passing url to module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

How do I get url into module?

```
module.exports = function(app, Reviews, Anon, User, url){
   var url = url;

  console.log("url", url)// url is undefined
  how to get url


  function postHandler(req, res){

  }


   app.post("/individual/"+ url + "/usefulness", postHandler)
};
```

call in routes.js

```
var usefulness = require("./usefulness")(app, Reviews, Anon, User, app.locals.url)
```

tried doing this in routes.js

```
   app.use("/*", function(req, res, next){
        app.locals.url = req.path;
        next()
    })
```

Edit: I also tried doing `app.set("url", app.locals.url)` in routes.js and do `var url  = app.get("url")` in usefulness.js

maybe I can't access app.locals if I don't access it in a handler for a route.

you see I can't do something like `var usefulness = require("./usefulness")(app, Reviews, Anon, User, req.path)` maybe if I could do something like that it would help.

Answer (score 0):

Since the value of the url is set after a request you can do the following

```
module.exports = function (app, Reviews, Anon, User) {
  return function (url) {
    app.post("/individual/"+ url + "/usefulness", function () {})
  }
}
```

And then on routes.js

```
var usefulness = require("./usefulness")(app, Reviews, Anon, User) 
// ...
app.use("/*", function(req, res, next){
   app.locals.url = req.path
   usefulness(apps.locals.url)
   next()
})
```

Dunno why you're creating a closure on Reviews, Anon and User though

Answer (score 0):

Express middleware defined via `app.use` is not executed until the route matching the pattern `/*` is reached. When the script is run, the `require("./usefulness")` function takes an undefined `app.locals.url` as an argument.

The only way to define `usefulness` with a valid `app.locals.url` argument would be to move the require line into the callback:

```
var usefulness;
app.use("/*", function(req, res, next){
    app.locals.url = req.path;
    usefulness = require("./usefulness")(app, Reviews, Anon, User, app.locals.url) 
    next();
})
```

Still, an endpoint matching `/*` needs to be reached before `usefulness` and `app.locals.url` are defined but app.locals.url will retain this `req.path` value for the lifetime of the application.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think `app.use("/"` is what I want. THANKS :)